# Buffer NULL!: Cannot allocate memory

Tags: c

I have written a program that takes MB's as 3 param and gives me the throughput time.

```
int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
 double kb = 0;
 int time_taken = 0;
 double throughput = 0;
 int i = 0;
 int w_rw = 0;
 int fd = -1;
 int bw = -1;
 unsigned long long nob = 0;
 char ip;
 char* file_name = "myfile";
 char* buff;
 struct stat info;
 struct timeval start_time,end_time;
 int mb = 1024 * 1024;

 /* Check the nos for W/RW and MBs*/
 if(1 == argc){
        printf("\n Missing 2 params R/RW & MB,Eg: execute ./a.out 2 100 \n");
        return 1;
 }
 if(argc < 4){
         w_rw = atoi(argv[1]);
         if(w_rw > 2){
                w_rw = 2;
         }
         nob = (atoi(argv[2]) * mb);
         printf("\n W/RW : %d BYTES : %u \n",w_rw,nob);
 }
 else{
        // Do Nothing
 }
 /* Allocate Buffer */
 buff = (char *)malloc(nob * sizeof(char));
 if(NULL == buff){
        perror("Buffer NULL!");
        return -1;
 }

 printf("\n File - Create,Open,Write,Close \n");

 for(i = 0; i < w_rw; i++){
        if(i == 0){
                printf("\n --- Write IO Performance--- \n");
        }
        else{
                printf("\n --- Re-write IO Performance--- \n");
                printf("\n Press any char to continue : \n");
                ip = getchar();
        }

        /* Open file*/
        if((fd = open(file_name,O_CREAT | O_RDWR))< 0){
                perror("Open failed!");
                return -1;
        }

        /*Calculating the start and end time of write*/
        gettimeofday(&start_time,NULL);
        if((bw = write(fd,buff,nob)) < 0){
                perror("Write failed!");
                return -1;
        }
        gettimeofday(&end_time,NULL);

        /*Calculating the throughput*/
        time_taken = (end_time.tv_sec - start_time.tv_sec);
        kb = bw/1024;
        throughput = kb/time_taken;

        /* Start */
        if(-1 == stat(file_name,&info)){
                perror("STAT Failed");
                return -1;
        }

        printf("\n Inode no: %d \n Blocks : %d \n",info.st_ino,info.st_blocks);
        printf("\n Start sec : %u \n",start_time.tv_sec);
        printf("\n End sec : %u \n",end_time.tv_sec);
        printf("\n Bytes written : %d bytes \n",bw);
        printf("\n Time_taken : %d secs \n",time_taken);
        printf("\n Throughput : %f kb/sec \n",throughput);

        close(fd);
 }

 unlink(file_name);
 return 0;
}
```

O/P:

[root@rw gfs]# ./a.out 2 76800

W/RW : 2 BYTES : 3221225472
Buffer NULL!: Cannot allocate memory

Comment: depends on your system.

Comment: Better use `size_t` for anything that has to do with allocations.

Comment: Also, don't cast the result of `malloc`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: Have you tried buying 80GB of RAM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are requesting a *huge* block of memory (78GB!) and `malloc` fails, as expected on any standard (desktop/laptop) computer.

In fact, you have:

```
int mb = 1024 * 1024;
// ...
nob = (atoi(argv[2]) * mb);
// ...
buff = (char *)malloc(nob * sizeof(char));
```

so `nob` is `1024 * 1024 * 76800` in your case.

Try with a smaller size and it will work.

Comment: But I need to test with the larger size of around 100G. I have my file system with 2TB capacity. Why I could not create such a big size? Does unsigned int and signed int matters

Comment: Nope. The point is that **you are requesting 78GB of RAM**. I strongly doubt that you have more than 78GB of RAM, or that your computer can handle 78G in virtual memory. You can achieve your goal by allocating a buffer whose size is a reasonable submultiple of the requested one (say, 32MB), then write it `n` times with a `for` loop.